# XNA - Foreach loop has strange behaviour

Tags: c#, foreach, xna

I am using XNA to build a game.

I have a foreach loop, that loops through a list with tiles. In the foreach loop, it will check if the mouse is clicked, if the mouse is on a tile and if the mouse is within a certain container.

Where it goes wrong, is inside the

```
MouseInput.IsTileHovered(tile, camera)
```

Each tile has it's own tile position, ranging from x=1 and y=1 to x=20 and y=15.
However, in the IsTileHovered() function, the tile position is always x=1 and y=1. This is not correct. As I stated, every tile has it's own position, which is unique. The tilePosition is used to calculate the worldPosition.

**The function with the foreach loop**

```
public void PlaceNewTileOnMap(MapEditorTile newTile)
{
    foreach (Tile tile in tiles)
    {
        if (MouseInput.IsClicked() && MouseInput.IsTileHovered(tile, camera)
            && MouseInput.IsMouseWithinTileContainer(backgroundRectangle))
        {
            tile.SetTileInfo(newTile.GetTileInfo());
            tile.SetCurrentFrame(newTile.GetCurrentFrame());

            Vector2 maxTiles = new Vector2(
                Constants.MAP_EDITOR_DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_TILES,
                Constants.MAP_EDITOR_DEFAULT_VERTICAL_TILES);

            MainTileGenerator tileGenerator = new MainTileGenerator(tile, tiles, maxTiles);
            UpdateCorrectedTiles(tileGenerator.CorrectTiles());
        }
    }
}
```

**The function that always receives a tile with position x=1 and y=1**

```
public static bool IsTileHovered(Tile tile, Camera camera)
{
    Vector2 mouseWorldPosition = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(newMouseState.X, newMouseState.Y),
        Matrix.Invert(camera.GetTransformation()));

    if (mouseWorldPosition.X > tile.GetWorldPosition().X
        && mouseWorldPosition.X < tile.GetWorldPosition().X + (tile.GetSingleElementSize().X * GameServices.UIService.ScreenScale)
        && mouseWorldPosition.Y > tile.GetWorldPosition().Y
        && mouseWorldPosition.Y < tile.GetWorldPosition().Y + (tile.GetSingleElementSize().Y * GameServices.UIService.ScreenScale))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I write the tilePositions to the console in the foreach loop, but before the if statement, I get all the unique tilePositions, which is correct. However when I do the same in the IsTileHovered() function, the tilePosition is x=1 and y=1, no matter what tile it uses from the list.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you might have a problem with a method returning tile position, but I suggest you run the problematic method step by step (F11 key) and determine where the problem originates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this so stupid from my side. It appears that the

```
MouseInput.IsClicked
```

return false on the second tile in the foreach, even when it is still the same frame. So all I had to do was change the order in the if statement from

```
if (MouseInput.IsClicked() && MouseInput.IsTileHovered(tile, camera)
        && MouseInput.IsMouseWithinTileContainer(backgroundRectangle))
```

to

```
if (MouseInput.IsTileHovered(tile, camera)
    && Input.IsMouseWithinTileContainer(backgroundRectangle)
    && MouseInput.IsClicked())
```

It will now check if the mouse is clicked at last, so now it will loop through all the tiles as I want. :)

Comment: Logically, you should filter out unnecessary checks by doing multiple consequent checks. Call the check method only when the mouse is clicked, then see if the mouse is within tile container or is hovering above a tile, (whichever goes first, I didn't quite catch it) and then do the last one, not all at once. But it's just for aesthetics mostly.

Comment: @user1306322 The C# `&&` operator short-circuits; that is, if the expression on the left turns out to be false, it doesn't bother evaluating the expression on the right because the result must be false anyway. Similarly, the `||` operator returns true if the left-hand expression is true, without bothering to evaluate the right-hand expression. Thus, `if(a && b) { ... }` is logically equivalent to `if(a) { if (b) { ... } }`, and faster.

Comment: @anaximander well, maybe that's true and Visual Studio's step by step execution doing all checks misled me into thinking otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be happening here. First time this happend to me.

Comment: See the "Remarks" sections on the MSDN pages regarding [the `&&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.71).aspx) and [the `||` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=vs.71).aspx). It's worth noting that running a program in debug mode changes numerous things about execution and flow; the evaluation of statements in logical checks may well be one of those things.